# Polymer how to set default value on paper select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using a paper-select element where I want to set some default value on DOM ready or based on some event fire.

```
 <dom-module id="paper-selects">
<template>
     <paper-select id="select-input-1" 
       multiple 
       label-field="name"
       bind-value="{{dataBind}}"
       on-input-changed="interestsChanged"
       nonmatching on-adding-item="addItem" select-on-blur 
       label="Select your favorite programming language"
       placeholder="please select your item"
       value="df"
       autofocus
     >
     </paper-select>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `paper-select` elements in the catalog, what is your source?